Get the url from a side inside a WebView in Maui.Net
I tested a bunch of changes in my code for getting the URL out of a webside from a WebView object and print the url to a entry.
private async void YoutubeWebView_Navigated(object? sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string currentUrl = await youtubeWebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync(
            "window.location.href;");
        urlEntry.Text = currentUrl;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"JavaScript execution error: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}

private void YoutubeWebView_Navigating(object? sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    urlEntry.Text = e.Url;
}

I tested the e.url. Not working. EvaluateJavaScriptAsync. Not working. change the Webview.source. Not working. Maybe One of your Proffs. can help me.

I test the code you provide, it can get e.url and set urlEntry.Text successfully. See this.

I compiled the app. at the first start it worked. but when i change the webside inside the webview it doesnt update the Url. it doesnt call the navigated nore the navigating method

You mean if you click a link in your webview, it will not update the Url(urlEntry.Text)?

yes sir. let me explain it to you. i have a app. there is a (like) textbox = urlEntry. under this entry is a webview. Inside the webview is loading a landing page. youtube!!. when i choose a Song, i click on it. the website is changing the Url. i want to print the url from the last site in to the urlentrybox

You mean like this?

Yes Sir right. when i open youtube and click some video then the video starts and the url from this video is showen in the urlentry

So, you want this or other effect?

no no that will be absolut perfect

You can try the following code:
xaml:
<Entry x:Name="urlentry" TextColor="OrangeRed"/>
 
<WebView Source="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-8.0"
         x:Name="webview"
         Navigating="webview_Navigating"
         Navigated="webview_Navigated"
         HeightRequest="500"/>

code behind:
private void webview_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    urlentry.Text = e.Url;
}
 
private async void webview_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    try 
    { 
        string currentUrl = await webview.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("window.location.href;"); 
        urlentry.Text = currentUrl; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"JavaScript execution error: {ex.Message}"); 
        throw; 
    }
}

You can try to set Source of WebView to .NET MAUI to see if urlentry.Text will update.
Update:
For Android, you can use WebViewClient.DoUpdateVisitedHistory() method of WebView if the base url doesnt change like it happens in single page applications and it detects URL change by javascript which does not lead to a web page reload. In addition, you can use WeakReferenceMessenger to exchange message(pass url to urlentry). Use the follwing steps:
Install the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package into your project and Add SendItemMessage.cs in your root directory:
public class SendItemMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string> 
{
    public SendItemMessage(string value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

Create MyClient.cs in your Platforms/Android, to get url and send it:
public class MyClient: WebViewClient
{
    public override void DoUpdateVisitedHistory(global::Android.Webkit.WebView? view, string? url, bool isReload)
    {
        var a = view?.Url;
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SendItemMessage(a));
        base.DoUpdateVisitedHistory(view, url, isReload);
    }
}

Modify your webview and receive url in MainPage.xaml.cs:
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ModifyWebView();
            WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SendItemMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
            {
                OnMessageReceived(m.Value);
            });
        }
 
        private void OnMessageReceived(string value)
        {
             urlentry.Text = value;
        }
 
        void ModifyWebView()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.SetWebViewClient(new Platforms.Android.MyClient());
#endif
            });
        }
....


It works for this site. i doent works with youtube.

I think i Cant reach the url of youtube. Thats the Problem

It's most likely related to youtube. Actually, the URL hasn't changed, it's still in the previous page.

Try other site?

I have a already winforms app with nearly the same classes. I get the url from youtube . But i Cant translate it for android

You can add the code to the post.

private void WebView2_SourceChanged(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2SourceChangedEventArgs e)
{
UpdateUrl();
}
#endregion
#region UpdateUrlMethode
//sagt schon alles
private void UpdateUrl()
{
if (this.webView21.Source != null)
{
URLtxtBox.Text = webView21.CoreWebView2.Source;
}
}

sorry im a newbie and i dont know how i have to post

Never mind. One question: Add a breakpoint on this line YoutubeWebView_Navigating, when you clik a link, will it hit the breakpoint to call YoutubeWebView_Navigating method?

I hope u mean the maui.net app. when i compile the app for debuging in the first round yes. when i change the link it skips both methods

Well, I am back and update the answer, wish it can help you :)

I have a Problem with the android.webkit.webview. this Nuget is Not accepted in my project. I think its a licence Problem.

Thank u very much for your effort

Or maby its blocked by youtube. Google worked and any other site

I have a Problem with the android.webkit.webview. this Nuget is Not accepted in my project. See this? Or maby its blocked by youtube. Yes, it should be the problem caused by YouTube.

But thank very much
